# Filtering Rows by Matching Column Value to Other Column Value in R

Tags: r, select, filter

I am quite new to R so this may be easier than expected, I might be overthinking.  Say I have a data.frame (df) and I want to pick rows that match criteria from another column, but the kicker is, I need the criteria to be exclusive to a group.  For example:

```
Column1    Column2    Column3 
Name1      Some Val   Criteria1
Name1      Unwanted   Also Unwanted
Name2      Some Val2  Criteria2
Name2      Unwanted   Also Unwanted
```

This might get confusing.  But basically, I want to select each Some Val based on its matching Criteria for each Name, so l want it to be:

```
Column1    Column2    Column3
Name1      Some Val1  Criteria1
Name2      Some Val2  Criteria2
```

The issue is that this is easy to do if selecting it over just a few Names.  But I have thousands, which means writing out thousands and names and thousands of different criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` you can do

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(Column1) %>%
    filter(str_detect(Column2, "Some Val"))
## A tibble: 2 x 3
## Groups:   Column1 [2]
#  Column1 Column2   Column3
#  <fct>   <fct>     <fct>
#1 Name1   Some Val  Criteria1
#2 Name2   Some Val2 Criteria2
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Column1    Column2    Column3
Name1      'Some Val'   Criteria1
Name1      Unwanted   'Also Unwanted'
Name2      'Some Val2'  Criteria2
Name2      Unwanted   'Also Unwanted'", header = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select rows from a group based on a *group-specific* criteria, you will need some kind of object that specifies the criteria for each group. You could do this with a data.frame (`criteria_by_group` in the code below).

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tibble)

df <- tribble(
  ~group_col, ~value_col, ~criteria_col,
  "Name1", "Some Val", "Criteria1",
  "Name1", "Unwanted", "Not Criteria1",
  "Name2", "Some Val2", "Criteria2", 
  "Name2", "Unwanted", "Not Criteria2"
)

criteria_by_group <- tribble(
  ~group_col, ~group_criteria,
  "Name1", "Criteria1",
  "Name2", "Criteria2"
)

df <- left_join(df, criteria_by_group, by = "group_col")

df
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   group_col value_col criteria_col  group_criteria
#>   <chr>     <chr>     <chr>         <chr>         
#> 1 Name1     Some Val  Criteria1     Criteria1     
#> 2 Name1     Unwanted  Not Criteria1 Criteria1     
#> 3 Name2     Some Val2 Criteria2     Criteria2     
#> 4 Name2     Unwanted  Not Criteria2 Criteria2

df %>%
  group_by(group_col) %>%
  filter(criteria_col == group_criteria[1])
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#> # Groups:   group_col [2]
#>   group_col value_col criteria_col group_criteria
#>   <chr>     <chr>     <chr>        <chr>         
#> 1 Name1     Some Val  Criteria1    Criteria1     
#> 2 Name2     Some Val2 Criteria2    Criteria2
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>